# How to quantify number of errors due to character encoding?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, windows-1252

I have a data process where strings are passed through many applications/databases with different character encodings. Some of the steps along the way are UTF-8 some aren't but the end database where I access that data is an oracle database that uses Windows-1252.

I am trying to convince my database administers that this is an issue but am having difficulty quantifying the magnitude of the issue. Is there a way to take the strings that are stored on my database and count the number of strings that contain at least one character that is showing up differently than it would have if the database used encoding UTF-8?

Comment: It really depends on how well or weird each system handles character encoding. If everything is doing their conversions properly then you'll simply end up with the smallest overlapping subset of characters supported by all involved character encodings (which will likely be ASCII plus a few more characters). If any intermediate systems "mangle" the data (i.e. don't really do conversion but pass it through mostly, but not quite), then the result can be much worse. How bad it is depends on what's in your system. Is it mostly US-american addresses? You'll survive. Other things ... less so.

Comment: I know that the systems are definitely not doing the conversions properly. For example on my oracle database, there are quite a few records that contain upside down question marks. When I trace these records back to the original input by the user these upside down question marks are emojiis or Chinese characters etc. My one attempt to quantify the issue was to count the number of records containing upside down question marks however I know this problem goes far beyond that and I think doing that misses quite a few records

Comment: To be clear, are you seeking an Oracle-based approach to examine arbitrary fields/tables in your database, and identify those characters which are valid UTF-8 characters, but not valid Windows-1252 characters? If so, [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) is a better place to ask your question. But if you are looking for a programming solution instead, you need to provide more details, starting with the language you will be using, and details of any effort you have made so far. Your question is a bit too general and abstract as it stands.